# Help with Homology Short Exact Sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I am having some trouble understanding some notes I found on the net which lead to a derivation of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. I was wondering if someone on hercould help me to understand the workings of these notes, below. The notes say the following:

“If $U$ and $V$ are open subsets of a manifold $M$, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is as follows: (We refer to the ’Homological Algebra’ notes for the result that a short exact sequence of chain complexes gives rise to a long exact sequence of the corresponding cohomology groups.)”

$0\rightarrow \Omega ^{*}\left ( U \cup V \right )\overset{f}{\rightarrow}\Omega ^{*}\left ( U \right ) \oplus \Omega ^{*}\left ( V \right )\overset{g}{\rightarrow} \Omega ^{*}\left ( U \cap V \right )\rightarrow 0$

Where:

$i_{U}:U\rightarrow U \cup V$, $i_{V}:V\rightarrow U \cup V$, $j_{U}:U \cap V \rightarrow U$, $j_{V}: U \cap V \rightarrow V$

$f=\left (i^{*}_{U},i^{*}_{V} \right )$ and $g=j^{*}_{U}-j^{*}_{V}$

Looking at these notes above, I think I see why $f$ is injective; since I think for a form $\alpha$ on $U\cup V$ to produce a zero on both U and V requires $\alpha=0$. I am not sure however why g is surjective. I am not sure why given any $\alpha$ on $U\cap V$, this $\alpha$ can be written as:

$\alpha=j^{*}_{U} \alpha_{U}-j^{*}_{V} \alpha_{V}$

for some $\alpha_{U}$ and $\alpha_{V}$ defined on $U$ and $V$ respectively. I am also not sure why there is a minus sign in this relationship instead of a plus sign. I imagine it is obvious, but I am just not seeing it.

Can anyone on here explain to me why any $\alpha$ on $U\cap V$ can be written this way, and why the minus sign?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : we want the sequence to be exact, in particular that $g \circ f = 0$. Let $\alpha \in \Omega(U \cup V)$. Then, $f(\alpha) = (\alpha_{|U}, \alpha_{|V})$ and $g(f(\alpha)) = g(\alpha_{|U}, \alpha_{|V}) = {\alpha_{|U}}_{U \cap V} - {\alpha_{|V}}_{U \cap V} = \alpha_{U \cap V} - \alpha_{U \cap V} = 0$. Notice that the $-$ sign was important.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I know the point is that we want to have a short exact sequence. Then everything follows. I know we want surjectivity, but I am not sure why we have surjectivity; this needs proof. I am not sure why any form on $U\cap V$, can be written as $\alpha=j^{*}_{U} \alpha_{U}-j^{*}_{V} \alpha_{V}$ for some $\alpha_{U}$ and $\alpha_{V}$. The hint suggests that we may want the two terms cancelling out to zero, but I still don't really see the answer to my question. I would ideally prefer the answer to hints which I probably wont get at  my level of experience.

Comment: I have just noticed the next section of the notes may actually partly answer my question. These notes present the following argument.

Comment: Let $\left \{ \rho_{U},\rho_{U} \right \}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to the open cover $U\cup V$. Then we can write $\alpha_{U\cap V}=\rho_{U}\alpha_{U\cap V}-\left ( -\rho_{V}\alpha_{U\cap V} \right )$. Then extend $\rho_{U}\alpha_{U\cap V}$ by zero to all of U. Likewise, extend all of $-\rho_{V}\alpha_{U\cap V}$ by zero to all of V.  Then rename as follows $\beta_{U}:=\rho_{U}\alpha_{U\cap V}$ , $\beta_{V}:=-\rho_{V}\alpha_{U\cap V}$. Then finally we have

$\alpha_{U\cap V}=J^{*}_{U}\beta_{U}-J^{*}_{V}\beta_{V}$

Comment: To anyone who knows this field, does the above paragraph answer my question on surjectivity?

Comment: I think I get the other part now. When $g$ acts on a general member of $\Omega ^{*}\left ( U \right ) \oplus \Omega ^{*}\left ( V \right )$, then $j^{*}_{U}$ and $j^{*}_{V}$ act on different forms ; and so the result will not be zero. But when they act on members that have come from $f$ acting on $\Omega ^{*}\left ( U \cup V \right )$, then $j^{*}_{U}$ and $j^{*}_{V}$ will act on the same form, thus their difference will return the desired 0 hence $g \circ f$ will return 0 as desired. I may not have got all this right, but I think it must be something like this. Thanks to above for the hint!

Comment: I think you got everything right. (Sorry my previous comment was wrong)

Comment: You're welcome ! (I did nothing thus, you found the argument by yourself)